# Serialization of JFrame removes JButton's ActionListener - Java

Tags: java, serialization, user-interface, deserialization, actionlistener

I'm relatively new to serialization, so I created a test application to mess around with it. I serialized a `JFrame` which had 3 added `JComponents`: a `JTextArea` and two `JButtons`. One button saved the `JFrame`'s state (i.e. serialization) and the other loaded the serialized JFrame (i.e. deserialization).

When I typed a message in the `JTextArea`, clicked the button to save the state, and then loaded the `JFrame` from the SER file, I got the exact same object (typed message and all) except that the buttons no longer worked.

Would someone mind explaining why this behaved the way it did?

P.S. I know that it's generally not a good practice to serialize GUI components, but this is for learning purposes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the class that was implementing `ActionListener` also implement `Serializable`, and that fixed the problem right up.